# Выноски-указатели для button или textView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Каким способом можно реализовать вот такие выноски (указатели, стрелки, "хвосты", callout'ы) для `Button` или для `TextView`.

На скрине отметил стрелкой:

[image: xml-макет]

В этом макете я их нарисовал на самой картинке. Что очень медленно и неудобно.

Comment: Очень интересная задача, с указателем проблем нет, ниже ответ. А вот, насчет точек деталей?

Comment: @eugeneek **eugeneek**, да задача былы бы интересная. Но я уже понял, что буду ее реализовывать простым и неинтересным методом. Просто в импортируемом графическом файле. Со вчерашнего дня я еще придумал каким образом мне ускорить и упростить использование такого подхода. Так что, пожалуй, он во мне победил.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [PointerPopupWindow](https://github.com/okry1123/PointerPopupWindow):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или другой вариант [QuickAction как в Twitter](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно еще проще: [BalloonPopup](https://github.com/BeppiMenozzi/BalloonPopup):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Barmaley**, спасибо за подробный развернутый ответ